# Comparer Class Most Efficient?

Tags: c#, comparison

Consider the following
A list of approximately 10,000 folders
Of these folders, a list of rules determine if they qualify to go to the next stage
The rules are a text based comparison such that
if folder name **contains** (...any of the following from a list of exceptions) - such that there is a one to many comparison for each folder, but the folder name string must contain (or must NOT contain) any of the strings it is compared do

I'm relatively new to C# so I'm not entirely sure what's under the hood of each class

Any advice in some general direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a performance problem, or are you trying to optimize the code before it has been written?

The `Comparer` class is typically not the topmost performant class of the .NET framework, but it has to cater for quite a lot of scenarios.

If you know the source and target types, you're usually better off implementing your own specific comparer class.

However, unless you know that you have a performance problem, I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 0):

First of 10 K folders is not a large number... So you might not want to worry about performance already.

So dont optimize...

After that you might want to consider the way you search your names... Instead of a seach for every single element, you could create a regexp that will perform all searches at once, but that is optimization without a real need...

First you need a reason to change the code